# Run-time error in VBA when trying to use Internet Explorer object

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer, runtime-error

I am trying to do some web-scraping in Excel-VBA and I am getting the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Unspecified error
```

I have narrowed it down to this code:

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False    '<- I get the error here

End Sub
```

The IE object seems to be created properly, as I can see it in the locals window.
I just can't use it for some reason.

It is confusing because it was working just a few hours ago. I even recovered a previous version of the file in case I accidentally changed something, but still it is not working anymore.

These are the references I have on:

[image]

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Try with InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: When setting `IE.Visible = False`, it should not show the visualization window. Do you mean this will show the IE window in the taskbar? You can try to kill all IE processes and execute the code again.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = true
```

if it works you may change

```
 IE.Visible = false
```

if you do not have InternetExplorer installed that could be the problem. (Edge browser is not InternetExplorer)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim elem as String
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = true`enter code here`
IE.Navugate2 "<write a url here>" ' eg. "www.wikipedia.org"
elem = IE.Document.GetElementById ("<seeking element id>").InnetText ;
```

Comment: After an update IE.navigate and IE.navigate2 opens Edge. Old code no more works from VBA in excel. I get the error "IWebBrowser2 failed". What a mess by Microsoft